# Is there a way to create a new Outlook email from Access 2002 without using the SendObject command?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, email-attachments

I have a client that is using Access 2002 because it allows Replication. He is using this on Windows 10 with Outlook from Office 365.

The goal is to create a new email with all of the info filled in and attach a scanned proposal so that my client can review the email, make any changes that he wants and then send it.

In Access, the SendObject command creates and opens a plain text email and while this email is open my Outlook macro to scan a document and attach it to the email will not run.

So I would like to create a new Outlook email from Access that allows me to run my Outlook macro.

Or if I could get Access 2002 to create an email and attach the scanned document to it, I think I could get by with using msgboxes to verify specific items.

Below is the Access macro with the SendObject command followed by the Outlook macro.

```
Private Sub EmailProposal_Click() 
'Access macro.
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stEmailAddress As String
Dim stSubject As String
Dim stMessage As String

    stDocName = "rptProposal"
    stEmailAddress = Forms!RequestForm!EmailAddress.Value
    stSubject = "PROPOSAL"
    stMessage = "Your proposal is attached." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "If you have any questions, please call us."

    'Email the proposal.
    DoCmd.SendObject acReport, stDocName, acFormatRTF, stEmailAddress, , , stSubject, stMessage
End Sub

Sub Scan()
'Outlook macro.
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

     On Error Resume Next
     Dim objCommonDialog As WIA.CommonDialog
     Dim objImage As WIA.ImageFile
     Dim strPath As String

     Set objCommonDialog = New WIA.CommonDialog
     'This shows the dialog box. I'd rather tell it what to do instead of having to manually choose each time.
     Set objImage = objCommonDialog.ShowAcquireImage        

     strPath = Environ("TEMP") & "\TempScan.jpg"            'Save the scan.
     If Not objImage Is Nothing Then
         objImage.SaveFile strPath        ' save into temp file
         On Error GoTo ErrHandler

         If TypeName(ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
             If ActiveInspector.IsWordMail And ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
               ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Inlineshapes.AddPicture strPath        'Insert into email. I want to attach it instead.
             End If
         End If
         Kill strPath
     Else
        MsgBox "The Scan macro in Outlook did not find a document." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _ 
        "Please place the proposal in the printer so it can be scanned.", vbOKOnly
     End If

lbl_Exit:
     Set objImage = Nothing
     Set objCommonDialog = Nothing
     Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
     Beep
     Resume lbl_Exit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to automate Outlook for sending out emails with the required content set up. Take a look at the following articles that give you the basics of Outlook automation:

- [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application)
- [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-other-office-applications)

```
Sub Send_Mail_Outlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "eugene@astafiev.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It's working great. Much appreciated! Any thoughts on how to run the scan macro from Access? I'm currently running it in the new Outlook email after the Access VBA has run so I can't attach it from there. Access doesn't like the AWI types in that sub. 
Currently, the Outlook Scan sub inserts the scanned item instead of attaching it like I want and shows a scanner dialog box when I would rather make it use the feeder with letter size. I realize these are new questions.

Comment: To get WIA commands to work in Access, turn on the reference for Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library.  To attach a file into an open email, `Set myItem = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    myItem.Attachments.Add strFileZip` where strFileZip contains the file string and name.

Comment: To set the scanner options and use the feeder,  `Dim Scanner As WIA.Device
DPI = 100
PP = 1 'No of pages
Set Scanner = Dialog1.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, False, False)
Scanner.Properties("3088").Value = 1 'Use the Document Feeder.
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6146").Value = 1 'Color intent. 4 is bw. 1 is color.
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6151").Value = 8.27 * DPI 'Horizontal extent
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6152").Value = 11# * DPI   'Vertical extent for letter` etc.